# How can I check the validity of a .xsig signature?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, xml-signature

Now we received two documents.

A PDF and a .xsig document containing the signatures over this PDF file.

I suposed we'd be able to verify the signatures in a way that directly relates both documents, but every place where I check the signature doesn't show any way to check the related file, and the only way I can think of, that is generating the PDF file hash and comparing it to the one referenced on the .xsig file doesn't seem to throw the same result.

So... any ideas on this?

I'm generating the PDF hash with an app called Autofirma, and comparing it to the hash stored on xsig file's CONTENT node.

Comment: .xsig contains XML signatures. The hash of the document is signed along with some additional attribute,s so you can not validate the signature directly. Try with https://valide.redsara.es/. If you are looking for code the solution is not trivial. You should read about XML signatures. Otherwise this question is off-topic

Comment: @pedrofb I'd already try validating at valide.redsara.es, but there I only can validate the signature... there isn't any way to link the signature to the original document so I can assure the document is valid and it hasn't been modified